# Change type of an object after its creation (typecasting in Python)

Tags: python, class, object, dynamic-programming, metaclass

In my project, I generate an object `obj` of type `CubicObject`. At runtime, a GUI setting should be allowed to change the type of `obj` to `Tofu` or `Box` (and back), depending on what the user wants to do and what (s)he thinks the object is best represented by. Then the user should benefit from specific algorithms implemented in the corresponding classes. I am looking for a nice implementation of this behaviour. I have played with the code below, which changes the `__class__` attribute, but I am sure that this is bad style.

```
class CubicObject(object):
    name = 'Baseclass'

    def __init__(self, sidelength):
        self.sidelength = sidelength


class Tofu(CubicObject):
    name = 'Class A'

    def eat(self):
        print("I've eaten a volume of %s. " % (self.sidelength**3))


class Box(CubicObject):
    name = 'Class B'

    def paint(self):
        print("I painted a surface of %s. " % (self.sidelength**2 * 6))

# user only knows the object is vaguely cubic
obj = CubicObject(sidelength=1.0)
# user thinks the object is a Box
obj.__class__ = Box
obj.paint()
# user changes mind and thinks its a piece of Tofu
obj.__class__ = Tofu
obj.eat()
obj.paint()  # generates an error as it should, since we cannot paint Tofu
```

My two questions are:

- What kind properties of class `A` are transferred to the object 'obj'
  when I change its `__class__` attribute? What functions are called
  and what attributes are updated, or how else does it happen that obj 
  changes its name to the one of A?
- What other, cleaner ways exist to implement the behaviour I want? If
  necessary, I could destroy the object `obj` and recreate another one,
  but in this case I would like to do so in a generic manner (like
  `obj = RoundObject(subclasstype='Tofu')` because of other parts of the
  code).

The underlying problem is that I allow the user to implement own functions in subclasses of `CubicObject` and that one should be able to switch between these subclasses while the program is running.

Comment: This looks like a massive XY problem. What exactly are you trying to do that requires this functionality?

Comment: Because I am pretty sure I can come up with a dozen examples that show why this is impossible.

Comment: I think that this is something you'd do in Java or C++, where there is type casting.

Comment: Type casting doesnt' change the type of an object. It just views it as a different type.

Comment: Maybe what he really wants is a wrapper class that could receive different inner delegate objects for the duration of run-time. That would make more sense.

Comment: Whenever  I hear typecasting I think: polymorphism, virtual function...

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge That's what I was thinking.

Comment: So indeed, Leonhard, I think that the hint about the inner delegate object that @synchronizer commented, helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Right, disregard the typecasting comment. It was more about the fact that Python has less of a notion about types (duck typing) when it comes to enforcing type rules, etc. In Java you can do what is asked with fields though,

Comment: I have tried to make the example more explicit. My current implementation already uses a delegate object, but it is impractical because it hides all the interesting functions in the API that I want to provide in that delegate object (I usually duplicate all functions of the delegate object, but that understandably confuses people). Would you say my way of dealing with the problem in the example is acceptable?

Comment: It seems to me that this proposal contravenes every principle of [SOLID design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What kind properties of class A are transferred to the object 'obj'
>   when I change its **class** attribute? What functions are called and
>   what attributes are updated, or how else does it happen that obj
>   changes its name to the one of A?

All instance assigned attributes are kept - that is, Python objects normally have a `__dict__` attribute where all instance attributes are recorded - that is kept. And the object's class effectively changes to the one assigned. (Python runtime forbids `__class__` assignment for objects which have a different memory layout). That is: all methods and class attributes on the new class are available for the instance, and none of the methods or class attributes of the previous class are there, as if the object had been created in this new class.
No side effects are triggered by the assignment (as in: no special method is called) 
So - for what you are making, it "works".

> What other, cleaner ways exist to implement the behaviour I want? If
>   necessary, I could destroy the object obj and recreate another one,
>   but in this case I would like to do so in a generic manner (like obj =
>   RoundObject(subclasstype='Tofu') because of other parts of the code).

Yes, as you've noted, this not is the best way of doing things.
What you could have is a class hierarchy with the distinct methods you need, that get your object as an attribute - and depending on what you are doing, you create a new object os this outer hierarchy - and keep your core object with its attributes unchanged. This is known as the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

```
class CubicObject(object):
    name = 'Baseclass'

    def __init__(self, sidelength):
        self.sidelength = sidelength


class BaseMethods(object):
    def __init__(self, related):
         self.related = related

class Tofu(BaseMethods):
    name = 'Class A'

    def eat(self):
        print("I've eaten a volume of %s. " % (self.related.sidelength**3))


class Box(BaseMethods):
    name = 'Class B'

    def paint(self):
        print("I painted a surface of %s. " % (self.related.sidelength**2 * 6))

# user only knows the object is vaguely cubic
obj = CubicObject(sidelength=1.0)
# user thinks the object is a Box
box  = Box(obj)
box.paint()

# user changes mind and thinks its a piece of Tofu
tofu = Tofu(obj)

tofu.eat()
# or simply:
Tofu(obj).eat()
```

You can roll it on your own, manual classes, or use a well known and tested library that implements features to automate parts of the process. One such library is  [`zope.interface`](https://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/), that allows you to write huge and complex systems using the adapter pattern. So you can have hundreds of different types of objects - you can mark them as having the interface "Cubic" as long as they have a `side_length` attribute. And then you cna have tens of classes that do "Cube" things with the `side_length` attribute - the `zope.interface` facilities will allow you to use any of these tens of classes with any of the objects that have the Cubic interface by simply calling the interface for the  desired method passing the original object as a parameter.

But `zope.interfaces` may be a little hard to grasp, due to poor documentation done as needed over nearly two decades of use (and at some point, people resorted to use XML files to declare interfaces and adapters - just skip any docs that deal with XML), so for smaller projects, you can just roll it manually as above.

> My current implementation already uses a delegate object, but it is
>   impractical because it hides all the interesting functions in the API
>   that I want to provide in that delegate object (I usually duplicate
>   all functions of the delegate object, but that understandably confuses
>   people).

Since your real-use example is big, that s a case to indeed learn and use `zope.interface` - but another workaround to a fully interface/registry/adapter system, if you want to permit access of several `Cube` methods on `Tofu` and others is to implement on the `BaseMethods` class I have above the magic  `__getattr__` Python method that would allow you to retrieve methods and attributes on the referred object in a transparent way, with no re-write needed:

```
class BaseMethods(object):
    def __init__(self, related):
         self.related = related

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.related, attr)
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation of the [borg pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/) could be of help here:

```
class CubicObject(object):
    name = 'Baseclass'

    def __init__(self, __shared_state, sidelength):
        self.__dict__ = __shared_state
        self.sidelength = sidelength


class Tofu(CubicObject):
    name = 'Class A'

    def eat(self):
        print("I've eaten a volume of %s. " % (self.sidelength**3))


class Box(CubicObject):
    name = 'Class B'

    def paint(self):
        print("I painted a surface of %s. " % (self.sidelength**2 * 6))
```

Now, make multiple instances that share the same state:

```
def make_objs(classes, *args, **kwargs):
    __shared_state = {}
    return tuple(cls(__shared_state, *args, **kwargs) for cls in classes)


box, tofu = make_objs(sidelength=1.0, classes=(Box, Tofu))
```

Switch back and force between them keeping the same state:

```
obj = box
obj.paint()
obj = tofu
obj.eat()
obj.paint()
```

The `sidelength` will be shared by both.

Comment: That could only remotely be of some use if none of the objects is to change state, in none of its facets.

Comment: BTW, your example will raise an error due to double declaration of argument `classes`

Comment: Works if you use only keyword arguments `box, tofu = make_objs(sidelength=1.0, classes=(Box, Tofu))` or put the classes first `box, tofu = make_objs((Box, Tofu), 1.0)`.